# Docfx, how can make it render correctly accents characters?

Tags: .net, documentation-generation, docfx

I'm compiling a documentation with DocFx from Visual Studio with the NuGet package.

I write in Italian and we have a lot of characters like: `à` `è` `ì` `ò` `ù`. In the final render, my page looks like this:

[image: Characters error image]

The final html looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it render correctly?

Comment: That's the same issue faced with web pages and applications. Somewhere, you are using an ASCII codepage. This could be the source file itself (saving eg as ANSI instead of UTF8), or using a hard-coded non-Unicode encoding, or the tooling may require an explicit encoding parameter.

Comment: I checked with Notepad++, my .md files are encoded in ANSI. How can I switch that directly from VS (2015)?

Comment: The `Save` button in `File > Save As` is actually a dropdown button. Select `Save with Encoding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue saving the `.md` file with `UTF-8` (without `BOM`) encoding.